# How to set Arduino Reset Function for reading DHT11 Sensor Only

Tags: arduino

While playing with the DHT11 Sensor, I realized that the Arduino discovers that the sensor is disconnected after being hard reset. My question is how can I reset the Arduino each minute while keeping the variables untouched because I have many variables that depend on the previous state. For example, when the Arduino detects the sensor is disconnected, I want the variable (i) to become equals to 2. This is what I tried. (It's definitely wrong, and still in development stage). Is it possible?

```
#include <dht11.h>
    int led1=10; //Green Light (Working)
    int  i=0;//Status variable
    int l=13;//Button Press indicator
dht11 DHT11;
#define DHT11PIN 7
    int  led2=12;//Red Light (Not working)
    int led3=11;//Warning Light (Yellow)
    int input=2; //LED Reset Button  
    int oldButtonState = LOW;
void setup()
{
   Serial.begin(9600);
   pinMode(input,INPUT);
   pinMode(led1,OUTPUT);
   pinMode(led2,OUTPUT);
   pinMode(led3,OUTPUT);
   pinMode(l,OUTPUT);  
}
void(* resetFunc) (void) = 0;
  void loop() {
for (int j=0;j<60;j++){
  int chk = DHT11.read(DHT11PIN);
Serial.print("Temperature (C): ");
  int temp=DHT11.temperature;   
  Serial.println((float)temp,2);
delay(100);
}
resetFunc();
  int newButtonState = digitalRead(input);
        if (newButtonState == HIGH && oldButtonState == LOW) {
    digitalWrite(l,HIGH);
    i+=1;}

    else if (newButtonState == LOW && oldButtonState == HIGH) digitalWrite(l,LOW);
    if (i == 3) {
      i = 0;
    }

    if(i==0){
      digitalWrite(led1,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(led3,LOW);
      digitalWrite(led2,LOW);
    }
    else if (i==1){
      digitalWrite(led1,LOW);
      digitalWrite(led3,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(led2,LOW);
    }
    else if(i==2){
      digitalWrite(led1,LOW);
      digitalWrite(led3,LOW);
      digitalWrite(led2,HIGH);
    }

     oldButtonState = newButtonState;

   }
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: why does the sensor disconnect? try to move `dht11 DHT11;` to loop()

Comment: @Juraj It does not disconnect, I'm planning to deploy this Arduino in a remote place with LEDs and Internet Connection. I won't be able to access the Arduino on a daily basis. I just want to know when does the sensor disconnect in case the sensor not functioning correctly.